# Get attribute of embed element and changes values in flashvars Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the value of flashvars attribute?

```
<embed src="http://wl2static.lsl.com/common/flash/as3/MemberApplet026.swf" 
id="opera_elb" width="100%" 
height="100%" 
allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" 
bgcolor="ffe8ef" 
quality="high" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
flashvars="muteaudio=0&amp;ishd=1&amp;ishq=0&amp;twoway=0&amp;proxyip=">
```

I am using `getElementsByTagName` to get the element.

```
var Em = content.document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
```

And replace values in flashvars

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var Em = content.document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
var str = Em[0].getAttribute('flashvars').innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("muteaudio=0","muteaudio=1");
document.getElementsByTagName("embed").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>
```

But when I try error: Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is a solution (strictly to change the attribute of `flashvars`!). First I think you have a few syntax errors within your JS. So I modified it and here is the JS:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
    var Em = document.getElementById('vid');
    var str = Em.getAttribute('flashvars');
     var contentSpot = document.getElementById("he");
           contentSpot.innerHTML = Em.getAttribute('flashvars');
    Em.setAttribute('flashvars', 'muteaudio=1')
//    contentSpot.innerHTML = Em.getAttribute('flashvars');/* I used this to see if the change occurred.*/
    }

window.onload = myFunction();
```

So `contentSpot` is a div element I created to observe the change.

the html is here:

```
<embed id="vid" src="http://wl2static.lsl.com/common/flash/as3/MemberApplet026.swf" 
id="opera_elb" width="100%" 
height="100%" 
allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" 
bgcolor="ffe8ef" 
quality="high" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
flashvars="muteaudio=0&amp;ishd=1&amp;ishq=0&amp;twoway=0&amp;proxyip=">
    <div id="he"> Hello</div> <!-- The created div to observe -->
```

Okay so here is my suggestion:

1)pop in the cleaned up code into a jsfiddle, then observe the content. 
2)Then remove the line: `contentSpot.innerHTML = Em.getAttribute('flashvars');` above the code: `Em.setAttribute('flashvars', 'muteaudio=1')`.
3) remove comments slashes and then hit ctrl + enter to observe the attribute change.

*really watch your "."/DOM syntax and case sensitivity.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: thank you for help. but i mean changes value in flashvars by default is muteaudio=0 and i need changes to muteaudio=1. this code don't changes value muteaudio=0 in flashvars. you have another way? thanks

Comment: Do you want the code to change it 'if' a user clicks/does something? You code have the embed object code remain as you posted it, then on an onclick event have it set the `flashvars` attribute to `"muteaudio=1&amp;ishd=1&amp;ishq=0&amp;twoway=0&amp;proxyip="`.

Comment: do you mean that you want the default value of flashvars to be `muteaudio = 1` instead of `0`? I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve